# How to use use es*-shims with laravel and browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, laravel-elixir, shim

Let us consider this `gulpfile.js`:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.coffee(['1.coffee', '2.coffee'], 'storage/app')
      .browserify('app.js', null, 'storage/app')
});
```

And now I'd like to add [some](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es5-shim) [shims](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-shim) [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es7-shim). For all I know, they doesn't return something, they change the environment. Which makes me think they must be run before any other code.

I could put `require('es5-shim'); require('es6-shim'); require('es7-shim');` into the beginning of the first file. But I don't like the idea, since I may eventually change the order and it will stop working. And I'm not sure, if they're guaranteed to come in the order I specified them.

So, how do I prepend a file? Or how do you people deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came up with:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir')
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat')
    fs = require('fs');

elixir.extend('inlineTask', function(func, watcher) {
    var task = new elixir.Task(func.name, func);
    if (watcher) {
        task.watch(watcher);
    }
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.coffee('**/*.coffee', 'storage/app/app.js')
        .browserify('app.js', 'storage/app/bundle.js', 'storage/app')
        .inlineTask(function bundleJs() {
            return gulp.src([
                    'node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js',
                    'storage/app/bundle.js'])
                .pipe(elixir.Plugins.if(elixir.config.sourcemaps, elixir.Plugins.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})))
                .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
                .pipe(elixir.Plugins.if(elixir.config.sourcemaps, elixir.Plugins.sourcemaps.write('.')))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
        }, 'storage/app/bundle.js')
        .version('js/bundle.js');
});
```

But note that tasks are [not run](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/382) in the order they specified in the `gulpfile.js` when running `gulp watch`. So before that it makes sense to run just `gulp`.

Also, `gulp` (or should I say `laravel-elixir`) [doesn't always detect](https://github.com/shama/gaze/issues/177) new files. Supposedly, when source files pattern didn't match any file, when `gulp` was run.